# How do you fix a large list of unknown files in Ebrowse?

Tags: search, c++

I'm trying to use the emacs Ebrowse tool. The issue I'm having is a great majority of the C++ files, from my BROWSE file, are showing up as (unknown) file type, resulting in me being unable to open those actual files. I'm pretty unfamiliar with this codebase so it wouldn't be as simple as doing a C-x f and opening each (unknown) file in that manner.

This project has about 9300 classes.

What is an approach I can use to resolve this issue so that I can easily search for files throughout this project, and continue to have Ebrowse capabilities such as searching for the usages of functions, classes, and variables on a project wide scale?